# Magento 2.4.4 checkout knockout 'Unable to process binding'

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs

No customisation on Magento frontend Message component (Magento_Theme/js/view/messages"), but I got this error after M2.4.4 update.

knockout.js:3753 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function(){return {
data:messages().messages,as:'message'} }"
Message: Unable to process binding "html: function(){return $parent.prepareMessageForHtml(message.text) }"
Message: $parent.prepareMessageForHtml is not a function

Comment: Hi there , can you please let us know is there any custom module or theme which is over-riding the default magento templates like xml , phtml or JS,HTML files ? And is the code deployment successful , please do share screenshots to help us analyse this issue more.

Comment: I dont have custom change on Messages, it is originally from vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/messages.phtml.

Comment: Okay , i think the up-gradation might have gone wrong and causing some missing files , have u tried removing the composer.lock file and re-running the command - composer install again and try that front-end page which is causing that issue ? And have you checked the java-script minify settings in the admin side.Thanks.